# Сортировка массива по родителю

Tags: php

Нужно отсортировать массив, чтобы дочерние элементы шли сразу после родителя. Сложность в том, что в корне не обязательно будут стоять элементы с `parentId = 0`, начинаться могут деревья с любого элемента.

```
function sortByParents(array &$array, $parentId = 0, &$result = [])
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['parentId'] == $parentId) {
            array_push($result, $value);
            unset($array[$key]);
            $this->sortByParents($array, $value['id'], $result);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Как можно доработать функцию?

upd: пример данных

начальный массив:

```
[
  'id' => 23,
  'parentId' => 21,
],[
  'id' => 25,
  'parentId' => 0,
],[
  'id' => 28,
  'parentId' => 25,
],[
  'id' => 31,
  'parentId' => 22,
],[
  'id' => 32,
  'parentId' => 25,
],[
  'id' => 34,
  'parentId' => 0,
],[
  'id' => 35,
  'parentId' => 0,
],[
  'id' => 37,
  'parentId' => 0,
],[
  'id' => 38,
  'parentId' => 0,
],[
  'id' => 39,
  'parentId' => 40,
],[
  'id' => 40,
  'parentId' => 21,
]
```

результат:

```
[
  'id' => 25,
  'parentId' => 0,
],[
  'id' => 28,
  'parentId' => 25,
],[
  'id' => 32,
  'parentId' => 25,
],[
  'id' => 34,
  'parentId' => 0,
],[
  'id' => 35,
  'parentId' => 0,
],[
  'id' => 37,
  'parentId' => 0,
],[
  'id' => 38,
  'parentId' => 0,
],[
  'id' => 23,
  'parentId' => 21,  // выше нет родителя с id = 21
],[
  'id' => 40,
  'parentId' => 21,
],[
  'id' => 39,
  'parentId' => 40,
],[
  'id' => 31,
  'parentId' => 22,  // выше нет родителя с id = 22
]
```

Comment: пример данных-то приведите, и что хотите получить

Comment: @teran добавила пример

Comment: фактически вам надо создать дерево, прицепить к нему корень, и обойти его, сортируя детей?